# installing the persian latex for Windows

Tags: xepersian, persian

How to install the Persian LaTeX? 
I searched a lot on the internet but there is not a good reference that explains how to install LaTeX.
Thanks so much.

Comment: Can you please be more specific about what you're trying to install? Are you trying to install support for the Persian language in LaTeX, or are you asking for help installing a Persian-specific TeX distribution? (You might also be interested in http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/5904/17423 for the future.)

Comment: If all necessary components are already installed to run LaTeX then [xeperain package](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/xetex/latex/xepersian?lang=en) will be of interest.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recommend **XePersian** package for typesetting Persian/Farsi in your document. For a quick start, see [ParsiLaTeX.com](http://www.parsilatex.com/) [quick start](http://www.parsilatex.com/wiki/%D8%A7%D8%B2_%DA%A9%D8%AC%D8%A7_%D8%B4%D8%B1%D9%88%D8%B9_%DA%A9%D9%86%DB%8C%D9%85%D8%9F)

If you have a working installation of [TeXLive](http://tug.org/texlive/) (use 2015 for the latest version) with `xepersian` package installed, you can try this minimal example:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{Tahoma}

\begin{document} 
سلام \lr{World}!
\end{document}
```

You should use **XeLaTeX** to typeset your document, like this:

```
> xelatex farsi.tex
```

In the [example section of the above site](http://parsilatex.com/examples/), you can find out more. You can see the documentation for `xepersian` and `bidi` packages by invoking:

```
> texdoc xepersian bidi
```

You can find almost all you need to typeset Persian/Farsi in these two manuals.

There are also other good packages like `arabi` that are usable with TeX engines other than XeTeX, but I think you will [get the best result with XePersian](http://www.parsilatex.com/wiki/%D9%85%D9%82%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%B3%D9%87%D9%94_%D8%B2%DB%8C%E2%80%8C%D9%BE%D8%B1%D8%B4%DB%8C%D9%86_%D8%A8%D8%A7_%D8%AF%DB%8C%DA%AF%D8%B1_%D8%AA%D9%88%D8%B2%DB%8C%D8%B9%E2%80%8C%D9%87%D8%A7%DB%8C_%D9%81%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%B3%DB%8C%E2%80%8C%D8%B4%D8%AF%D9%87%D9%94_%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AA%DA%A9).

If you do not have TeXlive, you can download ISO image [here](http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/Images/). Installation is rather straightforward.

If you are speak Farsi, you can ask your question in your language here:

http://qa.parsilatex.com/

[image: A Persian Q&A site for TeX, LaTeX, and friends]